# Ember + Rails API connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm trying to get to work EmberCLI frontend app with my Rails API. For some reason it does not work. When I visit 'localhost:4200/artists' I see nothing but h1 tag. No API data. JS Console is empty. Any ideas?

Here's my **adapter**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  itunes_id: DS.attr('integer'),

});
```

**Model**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  itunes_id: DS.attr('integer'),

});
```

**Router**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('artists');
});

export default Router;
```

**Route**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('artist');
  }
});
```

And **view**:

```
<h1> Artists </h1>

<ul>
  {{#each artists as |artist|}}
    <li>Hello, {{artist.name}}!</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have the ember inspector plugin? Try checking that and the network tab in the browser.

Comment: Also the thing you say is your adapter is a model. Also in your view/contoller your model data is available under `model`, not `artists`. You may want to set an alias in your controller for this.

Comment: The code you have under your heading "adapter" is the same code as is the code listed under "model".  Is that just a cut and paste error?  If so, can you post your real adapter?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Lux, the array of artists is made available to the template as the `model` property of the controller. This should work:

```
{{#each model as |artist|}}
  <li>Hello, {{artist.name}}!</li>
{{/each}}
```